# Where do other utilities fit in the MVC/MVP patterns?

Tags: model-view-controller, mvp

Where do utilities like database communication, cross-program communication, verifying model data, authorizing credentials and other utilities fit in the MVC/MVP pattern? Are they just independent members that communicate with the Model/Controller, or do they fit in the Model/Controller category?

Comment: At least in MVP, all of you mentioned should belong to the M area (just assume your V has no business logic, and the P is just a mediator between M and V). I guess the same is relevant to MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's depend of how you setup your project(s) and what framework(s) are you using. I have this blog post I used it as reference [A Better Understanding Of MVC (Model-View-Controller) Thanks To Steven Neiland](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2379-a-better-understanding-of-mvc-model-view-controller-thanks-to-steven-neiland.htm)